# Prove that $X$ is a finite set

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Base case: $7 \in X$

Recursive case: If $x \in X$, either $\dfrac{x}{2} \in X$ (if $x$ is even) or $3 \times x + 1 \in X$ (if $x$ is odd)

Prove that $X$ is a finite set by explicitly listing all of its elements. Show how each element has been derived.

I notice that using my calculator after a while it gets back to $7$, but how can I prove it? I haven't been exposed to such questions yet.

Comment: You don't get back to $7$. The first number to repeat itself is $4$.

Comment: The process goes as follows: $$4\to \frac 4 2 = 2\to \frac 2 2=1\to 1\cdot 3 +1=4\to \ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that $X$ is a finite set from what is given.  You can only prove that $$X^{*}=\{7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1\}\subseteq X,$$and note that $X=X^{*}$ is possible.  There are many infinite sets that are also consistent with the given information; for instance,
$$
X^{*} \cup \{8,16,32,64,128,\ldots\}
$$
is another perfectly good choice for $X$.

Comment: So they probably meant prove that $X$ is a finite set in the case that the base is $7$?

Comment: @Phaptitude Yes. What this answer proves is that $X$ isn't necessarily finite, hence what you're asked to prove is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct that it gets back to $7$.  You should discover that it has a number of terms, then arrives at the cycle $1,4,2$.  Your calculator work would be a proof if it were correct-as the next element in the chain is determined from the previous one alone, if you ever get back to an element you used before you have a cycle.

Comment: Oops, of course 2 is not an odd number..